# Copying pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, parameters, copy, initialization

I have a class A containing two pointers to objects of another class B. I want to initialize one pointer or the other depending on which one is passed to `init()`, which also takes other parameters. My situation is thus the following:

```
class A {

public:
    A();
    init(int parameter, int otherParameter, B* toBeInitialized);

protected:
    B* myB;
    B* myOtherB;

};
```

Now my point is that I want to call `init()` as:

```
init(640, 480, this->myB);
```

or

```
init(640, 480, this->myOtherB);
```

Now, my init is implemented as:

```
void init( int parameter, int otherParameter, B* toBeInitialized ) {

    toBeInitialized = someConstructorFunction(parameter, otherParameter);

}
```

The problem is that the two pointers are not initialized, I suspect that toBeInitialized is overwritten, but the original parameter is not modified.

I am doing something wrong?
Should I use references to pointers?

Thank you
Tommaso

Comment: That is a very horrible design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, change to

```
void init( int parameter, int otherParameter, B*& toBeInitialized ) {

    toBeInitialized = someConstructorFunction(parameter, otherParameter);

}
```

In your original code `toBeInitialized` is passed by value and only the local copy of the variable will be modified.

Answer (score 3):

This is obviously a cut-down problem, but as stated would it not be better to have something like this:

```
class A {

public:
    A();
    B* buildB(int parameter, int otherParameter);

protected:
    B* myB;
    B* myOtherB;

};
```

Then call the function as

```
this->myB = buildB(640, 480);
```

Converting the third parameter to be a reference to (or pointer to) the member would work, but it smells like your design might be wrong.

Comment: I know, but actually this method initializes more than one thing, so it is not possible to pass all of them with return.

Comment: @tunnuz: Then your design probably needs more work.  If you've got multiple sets of members which can be independently initialised, consider splitting them into separate classes.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `toBeInitialized` by value, so the value modified inside `init()` is not reflected outside. You need to either pass reference to `toBeInitialized` pointer or a double pointer. i.e. change init signature to
`init(int, int, B*&)` or `init(int,int,B**);`

Answer (score 1):

Consider using pointers to members.  (it will give you a little more safety.)

```
void A::init(int p1, int p2, B * A::* memberToInit)
{
    this->*memberToInit = SomeConstructorFunc(p1, p2);
}
```

And the usage would be

```
myObject.init(480, 620, &A::myB);
```